# Install Ubuntu onto Old Asus EeePC 1215N?

Tags: asus, eeepc, intel-atom

I have my old netbook that's showing it's age I guess. Windows 7 seems boggy and slow (not that it was ever fast here).

Below is some of the hardware. I am looking for something more light weight and something I can use mostly for browsing and some light text editing and thought maybe Ubuntu (or an older version) might be a bit better for my needs. The trouble is I don't want to hop right in and discover that I'll need a ton of obscure patches and some very specific installation steps that a layman can't simply know.

I just want to clearly know if it is doable, recommended, and not something I'm going to waste a weekend trying to patch?

Thanks in advance for the advice and answers.

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium    
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601  
Other OS Description    Not Available   
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation   
System Manufacturer ASUSTeK Computer INC.    
System Model    1215N   
System Type X86-based PC    
Processor   Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D525   @ 1.80GHz, 1800 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4       Logical Processor(s)   
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. 0503, 9/7/2010 
SMBIOS Version  2.6 
Windows Directory   C:\windows  
System Directory    C:\windows\system32 
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1 
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7601.17514"  
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 3.00 GB 
Total Physical Memory   2.74 GB 
Available Physical Memory   857 MB  
Total Virtual Memory    5.48 GB 
Available Virtual Memory    3.45 GB 
Page File Space 2.74 GB 
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: It is possible. Install Lubuntu. I installed it on this laptop and it works well.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you. I didn't even know there was such a thing as Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you're wondering you can install Ubuntu on this configuration, sure why not. [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) is a lighter version you can try out. After installing every OS you need to spend a little time to make things settled so after installation you have to run

> sudo apt-get update

If you faced any unusual problem you can write it here.